# Remove last element after append

Tags: jquery, image, append, element

I have the following where `#maincontent` contains some images that will load into `#gallery`. The problem right now is that if I click on `#maincontent img` and load different images into `#gallery` for a lot of times, the loading just got draggier and draggier. Is it because when I click on the next image, it's simply on top of the previous image and the images just pile up over time? I'm not very familiar with `.append()` and `.last()` and I'm just wondering how to remove the previously loaded image after the newest image is loaded. I've tried `$('img:last-child', this).remove()` but it doesn't seem to work, so I just wonder if I'm on the right track.

```
$('#maincontent img').click(function(){
    $myFile = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#gallery').append('<img src="'+$myFile+'" />');
    $('#gallery img').last().css('display','none').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append` just add the images after each other within `#gallery`, and later you just hide the last one with your code. That means your page will load all the images but you just display the last one.

However, if you want to just display the latest image, you can just clear the `#gallery` and add the new image:

```
 $('#content').find('img').removeClass('lastitem');//we will add this class to the new image item, so we clear it from the previous images if any

var $image = $('<img class="lastitem"  src="http://armagetron.co.uk/mods/images/sky1.png" />');
$image.hide();//hide the image first
$('#content').append($image);//append the hidden image 

$image.fadeIn(800, function () {//show the image, when it is shown, hide the rest of it 
    $('#content').find('img').not('.lastitem').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/ma6LjfkL/1/

Second approach: `.prevAll`

```
 $('a').click(function () {
    var $image = $('<img class="lastitem"  src="http://armagetron.co.uk/mods/images/sky1.png" />');
    $image.hide();
    $('#content').append($image);

    $image.fadeIn(800, function () {
       $image.prevAll().fadeOut(500, function () {
          $(this).remove();
       });
    });
 })
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/ma6LjfkL/1/

Comment: But I don't want to clear the previous image until after the newest image is loaded for the fade-in-from-last-image effect (from $('#gallery img').last().css('display','none').fadeIn();), and also now it allows for reclicking on the thumbnail (#maincontent img) when the image is already loaded in #gallery, maybe there's another way to prevent that?